# Ho to delete Kali Linux partition?

Tags: disk

I installed Ubuntu 64bits alongside with Kali linux and now i want to delete the Kali so that Ubuntu takes all the disk space (1 Tb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Kali Linux is not an official Ubuntu flavor and is thus off-topic here. Apart from that, your question is not clear enough; do you want to delete Kali Linux from your disk or to only delete one of the partitions?

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot a live DvD/USB.
2. Use Gparted and delete the Kali partiton.
3. Resize the Ubuntu partition so it takes up the rest of the drive.
4. Apply the changes.
5. Use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

Try the program GParted. You can use it to delete a partition and then resize another existing one to take up its space.